# How to check if I have retina ready display on Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, retina-display

I am not sure If I have retina ready display on Macbook Pro. I can just see that the display is better than on older Macbook. Is there a way to check it without reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "retina ready" displays. There are only Macs with or without a retina display. Additionally, this is not programming question, this should have been asked on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Go to the Apple menu, select "About this Mac." Click "More Info..." on the window that appears. On a retina Mac, you will read something like "Retina, Mid 2012."

Comment: System Preferences > Displays will give you a clear idea.